# TVirtualTable or DAC to extract UTF-8 XML

Tags: xml, delphi, utf-8, dac

In Delphi, is there an easy way to extract data from a `TVirtualTable` or DAC, either:

1. using `SaveToXml()` to convert ADO XML into UTF-8 XML?
2. while using `SaveToFile()` saves the data in a "weird" binary XML, is there a Delphi code to change that to UTF-8 XML?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. XML is XML, regardless of who produces it. What "weird" XML are you referring to exactly? And why do you think "ADO XML" is not already valid XML, or in UTF-8?  You need to provide more details.

Comment: Hi Remy Lebeau, yes of course I agree with you but I need my XML to be exactly in the format of UTF-8. When using virtual tables from Delphi, it only allowed the ADO-xml format or binary xml ( with extra symbols that get added on) as an output so I was wondering if users knew an easy way to convert the ado-xml or the binary xml into uft-8-xml in Delphi… In any case thanks in advance!

Comment: XML is XML, period. Maybe the ADO XML is simply encoded in a different charset, like UTF-16. Do a charset conversion. Maybe the "binary XML" is actually another data format that happens to contain XML elements inside of it.  You would have to parse the format to extract the XML.